# Why initWithSpriteFrameName() and initWithFile() have different effect on Sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-x, sprite, init

I need a shatter effect, I can init my sprite with these two different methods successfully, but the shatter effect is different.

1. [The Effect I use initWithFile()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKS0Q.png)
2. [The Effect I use initWithSpriteFrameName()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLzlt.png)

(Ignore the text in the images, the below is the code)

```
bool ShatterSprite::init(const string &texFileName, float gridSideLen, GameTextureResType resType)
{
    m_gridSideLen = gridSideLen;
    switch (resType) {
        case PLIST:
            Sprite::initWithSpriteFrameName(texFileName); //sprite Frame
            break;
        case LOCAL:
            Sprite::initWithFile(texFileName);
            break;
        default:
            CCASSERT(0, "no here");
            break;
    }
    createShatter();
    return true;
}
```

The method I use initWithSpriteFrameName cannot get the effect I need, somebody can tell me the reason?

Comment: I use the shatter method ref to https://github.com/wantnon2/EffectNodes-for-cocos2dx/tree/v3

Answer (score 0):

initWithSpriteFrameName requires frame name and initWithFile requires file name. You are sending same in both. file means actual file on disk and frame means the frame name you have cached in memory. From following code you can add Frames in memory

```
SpriteFrameCache* cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("animations/grossini.plist");
```

Comment: I have added Frames before, and I can init my Sprite with initWithSpriteFrameName successfully. However, the sprite init with initWithSpriteFrameName have different shatter  effect with initWithFile.

Comment: Give some more explanation of your issue because for me both works equally and never act differently.

Comment: Ref to https://github.com/wantnon2/EffectNodes-for-cocos2dx/tree/v3, I achieve my shatter effect. According to his example, I use a .png file, it can realize shatter effect. However, when I use .plist file, I cannot realize that effect.

Comment: If still your problem resides. can you share the plist and associated png?

Comment: Thank you very much, and I have committed a part of codes and resources to GitHub: https://github.com/LongJDoing/Question_Demo/tree/master/ShatterEffect